# Sniffing fragments tcp packets with c

Tags: c, linux, tcp, packet-sniffers

I have this code from https://www.binarytides.com/packet-sniffer-code-in-c-using-linux-sockets-bsd-part-2/

```
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<netdb.h>
#include<stdio.h>   //For standard things
#include<stdlib.h>  //malloc
#include<string.h>  //strlen

#include<netinet/ip_icmp.h> //Provides declarations for icmp header
#include<netinet/udp.h> //Provides declarations for udp header
#include<netinet/tcp.h> //Provides declarations for tcp header
#include<netinet/ip.h>  //Provides declarations for ip header
#include<netinet/if_ether.h>    //For ETH_P_ALL
#include<net/ethernet.h>    //For ether_header
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<sys/ioctl.h>
#include<sys/time.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<unistd.h>

void ProcessPacket(unsigned char* , int);
void print_ip_header(unsigned char* , int);
void print_tcp_packet(unsigned char * , int );
void print_udp_packet(unsigned char * , int );
void print_icmp_packet(unsigned char* , int );
void PrintData (unsigned char* , int);

FILE *logfile;
struct sockaddr_in source,dest;
int tcp=0,udp=0,icmp=0,others=0,igmp=0,total=0,i,j; 

int main()
{
    int saddr_size , data_size;
    struct sockaddr saddr;

    unsigned char *buffer = (unsigned char *) malloc(65536); //Its Big!

    logfile=fopen("log.txt","w");
    if(logfile==NULL) 
    {
        printf("Unable to create log.txt file.");
    }
    printf("Starting...\n");

    int sock_raw = socket( AF_PACKET , SOCK_RAW , htons(ETH_P_ALL)) ;
    //setsockopt(sock_raw , SOL_SOCKET , SO_BINDTODEVICE , "eth0" , strlen("eth0")+ 1 );

    if(sock_raw < 0)
    {
        //Print the error with proper message
        perror("Socket Error");
        return 1;
    }
    while(1)
    {
        saddr_size = sizeof saddr;
        //Receive a packet
        data_size = recvfrom(sock_raw , buffer , 65536 , 0 , &saddr , (socklen_t*)&saddr_size);
        if(data_size <0 )
        {
            printf("Recvfrom error , failed to get packets\n");
            return 1;
        }
        //Now process the packet
        ProcessPacket(buffer , data_size);
    }
    close(sock_raw);
    printf("Finished");
    return 0;
}

void ProcessPacket(unsigned char* buffer, int size)
{
    //Get the IP Header part of this packet , excluding the ethernet header
    struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr*)(buffer + sizeof(struct ethhdr));
    ++total;
    switch (iph->protocol) //Check the Protocol and do accordingly...
    {
        case 1:  //ICMP Protocol
            ++icmp;
            //print_icmp_packet( buffer , size);
            break;

        case 2:  //IGMP Protocol
            ++igmp;
            break;

        case 6:  //TCP Protocol
            ++tcp;
            print_tcp_packet(buffer , size);
            break;

        case 17: //UDP Protocol
            ++udp;
            print_udp_packet(buffer , size);
            break;

        default: //Some Other Protocol like ARP etc.
            ++others;
            break;
    }
    printf("TCP : %d   UDP : %d   ICMP : %d   IGMP : %d   Others : %d   Total : %d\r", tcp , udp , icmp , igmp , others , total);
}

void print_ethernet_header(unsigned char* Buffer, int Size)
{
    struct ethhdr *eth = (struct ethhdr *)Buffer;

    fprintf(logfile , "\n");
    fprintf(logfile , "Ethernet Header\n");
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Destination Address : %.2X-%.2X-%.2X-%.2X-%.2X-%.2X \n", eth->h_dest[0] , eth->h_dest[1] , eth->h_dest[2] , eth->h_dest[3] , eth->h_dest[4] , eth->h_dest[5] );
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Source Address      : %.2X-%.2X-%.2X-%.2X-%.2X-%.2X \n", eth->h_source[0] , eth->h_source[1] , eth->h_source[2] , eth->h_source[3] , eth->h_source[4] , eth->h_source[5] );
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Protocol            : %u \n",(unsigned short)eth->h_proto);
}

void print_ip_header(unsigned char* Buffer, int Size)
{
    print_ethernet_header(Buffer , Size);

    unsigned short iphdrlen;

    struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr *)(Buffer  + sizeof(struct ethhdr) );
    iphdrlen =iph->ihl*4;

    memset(&source, 0, sizeof(source));
    source.sin_addr.s_addr = iph->saddr;

    memset(&dest, 0, sizeof(dest));
    dest.sin_addr.s_addr = iph->daddr;

    fprintf(logfile , "\n");
    fprintf(logfile , "IP Header\n");
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-IP Version        : %d\n",(unsigned int)iph->version);
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-IP Header Length  : %d DWORDS or %d Bytes\n",(unsigned int)iph->ihl,((unsigned int)(iph->ihl))*4);
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Type Of Service   : %d\n",(unsigned int)iph->tos);
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-IP Total Length   : %d  Bytes(Size of Packet)\n",ntohs(iph->tot_len));
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Identification    : %d\n",ntohs(iph->id));
    //fprintf(logfile , "   |-Reserved ZERO Field   : %d\n",(unsigned int)iphdr->ip_reserved_zero);
    //fprintf(logfile , "   |-Dont Fragment Field   : %d\n",(unsigned int)iphdr->ip_dont_fragment);
    //fprintf(logfile , "   |-More Fragment Field   : %d\n",(unsigned int)iphdr->ip_more_fragment);
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-TTL      : %d\n",(unsigned int)iph->ttl);
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Protocol : %d\n",(unsigned int)iph->protocol);
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Checksum : %d\n",ntohs(iph->check));
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Source IP        : %s\n",inet_ntoa(source.sin_addr));
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Destination IP   : %s\n",inet_ntoa(dest.sin_addr));
}

void print_tcp_packet(unsigned char* Buffer, int Size)
{
    unsigned short iphdrlen;

    struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr *)( Buffer  + sizeof(struct ethhdr) );
    iphdrlen = iph->ihl*4;

    struct tcphdr *tcph=(struct tcphdr*)(Buffer + iphdrlen + sizeof(struct ethhdr));

    int header_size =  sizeof(struct ethhdr) + iphdrlen + tcph->doff*4;

    fprintf(logfile , "\n\n***********************TCP Packet*************************\n");  

    print_ip_header(Buffer,Size);

    fprintf(logfile , "\n");
    fprintf(logfile , "TCP Header\n");
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Source Port      : %u\n",ntohs(tcph->source));
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Destination Port : %u\n",ntohs(tcph->dest));
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Sequence Number    : %u\n",ntohl(tcph->seq));
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Acknowledge Number : %u\n",ntohl(tcph->ack_seq));
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Header Length      : %d DWORDS or %d BYTES\n" ,(unsigned int)tcph->doff,(unsigned int)tcph->doff*4);
    //fprintf(logfile , "   |-CWR Flag : %d\n",(unsigned int)tcph->cwr);
    //fprintf(logfile , "   |-ECN Flag : %d\n",(unsigned int)tcph->ece);
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Urgent Flag          : %d\n",(unsigned int)tcph->urg);
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Acknowledgement Flag : %d\n",(unsigned int)tcph->ack);
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Push Flag            : %d\n",(unsigned int)tcph->psh);
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Reset Flag           : %d\n",(unsigned int)tcph->rst);
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Synchronise Flag     : %d\n",(unsigned int)tcph->syn);
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Finish Flag          : %d\n",(unsigned int)tcph->fin);
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Window         : %d\n",ntohs(tcph->window));
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Checksum       : %d\n",ntohs(tcph->check));
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Urgent Pointer : %d\n",tcph->urg_ptr);
    fprintf(logfile , "\n");
    fprintf(logfile , "                        DATA Dump                         ");
    fprintf(logfile , "\n");

    fprintf(logfile , "IP Header\n");
    PrintData(Buffer,iphdrlen);

    fprintf(logfile , "TCP Header\n");
    PrintData(Buffer+iphdrlen,tcph->doff*4);

    fprintf(logfile , "Data Payload\n");    
    PrintData(Buffer + header_size , Size - header_size );

    fprintf(logfile , "\n###########################################################");
}

void print_udp_packet(unsigned char *Buffer , int Size)
{

    unsigned short iphdrlen;

    struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr *)(Buffer +  sizeof(struct ethhdr));
    iphdrlen = iph->ihl*4;

    struct udphdr *udph = (struct udphdr*)(Buffer + iphdrlen  + sizeof(struct ethhdr));

    int header_size =  sizeof(struct ethhdr) + iphdrlen + sizeof *udph;

    fprintf(logfile , "\n\n***********************UDP Packet*************************\n");

    print_ip_header(Buffer,Size);           

    fprintf(logfile , "\nUDP Header\n");
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Source Port      : %d\n" , ntohs(udph->source));
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Destination Port : %d\n" , ntohs(udph->dest));
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-UDP Length       : %d\n" , ntohs(udph->len));
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-UDP Checksum     : %d\n" , ntohs(udph->check));

    fprintf(logfile , "\n");
    fprintf(logfile , "IP Header\n");
    PrintData(Buffer , iphdrlen);

    fprintf(logfile , "UDP Header\n");
    PrintData(Buffer+iphdrlen , sizeof *udph);

    fprintf(logfile , "Data Payload\n");    

    //Move the pointer ahead and reduce the size of string
    PrintData(Buffer + header_size , Size - header_size);

    fprintf(logfile , "\n###########################################################");
}

void print_icmp_packet(unsigned char* Buffer , int Size)
{
    unsigned short iphdrlen;

    struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr *)(Buffer  + sizeof(struct ethhdr));
    iphdrlen = iph->ihl * 4;

    struct icmphdr *icmph = (struct icmphdr *)(Buffer + iphdrlen  + sizeof(struct ethhdr));

    int header_size =  sizeof(struct ethhdr) + iphdrlen + sizeof icmph;

    fprintf(logfile , "\n\n***********************ICMP Packet*************************\n"); 

    print_ip_header(Buffer , Size);

    fprintf(logfile , "\n");

    fprintf(logfile , "ICMP Header\n");
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Type : %d",(unsigned int)(icmph->type));

    if((unsigned int)(icmph->type) == 11)
    {
        fprintf(logfile , "  (TTL Expired)\n");
    }
    else if((unsigned int)(icmph->type) == ICMP_ECHOREPLY)
    {
        fprintf(logfile , "  (ICMP Echo Reply)\n");
    }

    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Code : %d\n",(unsigned int)(icmph->code));
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Checksum : %d\n",ntohs(icmph->checksum));
    //fprintf(logfile , "   |-ID       : %d\n",ntohs(icmph->id));
    //fprintf(logfile , "   |-Sequence : %d\n",ntohs(icmph->sequence));
    fprintf(logfile , "\n");

    fprintf(logfile , "IP Header\n");
    PrintData(Buffer,iphdrlen);

    fprintf(logfile , "UDP Header\n");
    PrintData(Buffer + iphdrlen , sizeof icmph);

    fprintf(logfile , "Data Payload\n");    

    //Move the pointer ahead and reduce the size of string
    PrintData(Buffer + header_size , (Size - header_size) );

    fprintf(logfile , "\n###########################################################");
}

void PrintData (unsigned char* data , int Size)
{
    int i , j;
    for(i=0 ; i < Size ; i++)
    {
        if( i!=0 && i%16==0)   //if one line of hex printing is complete...
        {
            fprintf(logfile , "         ");
            for(j=i-16 ; j<i ; j++)
            {
                if(data[j]>=32 && data[j]<=128)
                    fprintf(logfile , "%c",(unsigned char)data[j]); //if its a number or alphabet

                else fprintf(logfile , "."); //otherwise print a dot
            }
            fprintf(logfile , "\n");
        } 

        if(i%16==0) fprintf(logfile , "   ");
            fprintf(logfile , " %02X",(unsigned int)data[i]);

        if( i==Size-1)  //print the last spaces
        {
            for(j=0;j<15-i%16;j++) 
            {
              fprintf(logfile , "   "); //extra spaces
            }

            fprintf(logfile , "         ");

            for(j=i-i%16 ; j<=i ; j++)
            {
                if(data[j]>=32 && data[j]<=128) 
                {
                  fprintf(logfile , "%c",(unsigned char)data[j]);
                }
                else 
                {
                  fprintf(logfile , ".");
                }
            }

            fprintf(logfile ,  "\n" );
        }
    }
}
```

When Udp packet arrived the code parse it well.

The problem is that tcp packet sometime fragments so I see with `print_tcp_packet` only splited data.

Wireshark know how to merge 2 fragments packets to 1.

How can I do that with that code?

Maybe using `recv` instead of `recvfrom` will fox that? How can I use `recv` fir sniffing?

Answer (score 1):

[RFC 791](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791) describes fragmentation rules for IP packets.

If there's more fragments to come, the packet will have More Fragments (MF) flag set, and each fragment will have its offset in Fragment Offset field. If you receive a packet with MF flag set, you should delay your processing until all fragments with the same Identification value are received, and then combine them into a single packet.

Aside from that, TCP packets are subject of TCP segmentation. Single buffer sent by `send` operation can be split into multiple network packets, according to negotiated MSS value. Similarly, multiple short buffers can end up within a single network packet. After all, TCP is a stream protocol.

Comment: *"Single buffer sent by send operation can be split into multiple network packets..."* - correct. Just to add: multiple sends might end up within the same packet.

Comment: @Alex Skalozub So if I use `recvfrom` or `recv` it doesn't help for this? So how can I handle tcp segmentation and fragmentation  with my code please??

Comment: For IP fragmentation, you can have a packet queue. When receiving a packet with a non-zero Fragment Offset, you search the queue by Identification number and copy data at the given offset, updating headers like length/crc/flags. Then you dequeue completed packets (with MF = 0) for processing. As of TCP segmentation, you really can't do anything about it. If you want something like Wireshark's "follow TCP stream" feature you just concatenate data from packets with matching src/dst addresses and ports.